# External Monitor with laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, display, fonts, display-resolution

I recently switched to linux(Ubuntu 22.04) from windows 10, am using Dell inspiron 3579 laptop display as well as external 1920x1080p monitor. I have tried using fractional scaling but the text on my laptop becomes blurry and simultaneously increases the font size on my external monitor.
I also tried the scaling using XRANDR doesn't work for me.

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --pos 1920x0 --scale 1x1  --output eDP-1 --auto --scale 1.5x1.5 --pos 0x0
```

But the screen is overlapping. Thereby I moved back to wayland from x11.

output of xrandr --listmonitors

```
0: +*XWAYLAND1 1920/290x1080/170+0+0  XWAYLAND1
 1: +XWAYLAND0 1920/530x1080/300+1920+0  XWAYLAND0
```

Is there a way to scale the font size on my 13 inch laptop to fit with it's DPI rather than relative scaling, or else a better scaling xrandr script. I am open to fixes with X11 as well as wayland, whichever works.
Thank you.

Comment: I switched from Wayland to Xorg In Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS, and then it worked with an extenal screen (without further tweaks) in my Dell Precision m4800 with nvidia graphics.

Comment: @yuri shard2, you could try switching the driver to Nouveau, reboot and login with Ubuntu instead of Ubuntu Xorg.